# Joint CDF of a uniform RV with its square

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed with mean zero, $X \sim \mathcal{U}(-a,a)$, and a cumulative distribution function (CDF) denoted $F$.

I am interested in finding the probability $P(X^2 - X<c)$, where $c$ is a constant.

I know that I would need the joint CDF in order to compute it. I can arrive at the distributions for $X^2$, which is not uniformly distributed. The CDF for $X^2$,denoted $G(x)$, that I obtain is $G(x)=F(\sqrt{x}) - F(-\sqrt{x})$ and of course from there I can arrive at the pdf.

I am aware that in general it is typically not possible to infer the joint distribution from the marginals in the case of dependent random variables, so at this point I am kind of stuck. As far as I know, in general there could be infinitely many joint distributions that fit two marginals.

Nevertheless, is it possible in this case of uniform distribution to solve for the joint CDF?

Comment: "I would need the joint CDF" Why? Joint CDF of which variables?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Perhaps I am completely on the wrong path. I thought I would need the joint cdf of $Y=X^2$ and $X$ and these are dependent random variables with different distributions, which might complicate things. Perhaps I am simply too confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider the event $X^2 - X<c$. See that this corresponds to $ x_1 \le X  \le x_2$, where $x_1,x_2$ are the roots of $X^2 - X =c$.  You should be able to compute this probability in terms of $F_X$ (or simply use the information that $X$ is uniform...)

Comment: Thank you so much! You've made my day! In hindsight I don't know why I didn't think about it that way!